# From leetcode:allocation failure GC in old space requested?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

[The original address](https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock/description/)

**This is my code:**

```js
var maxProfit = function(prices) {
  var tmp = [];
  for(let i = 0;i<prices.length;i++){
   for(let j =i+1;j<prices.length;j++){
    tmp.push(prices[j]-prices[i]);
   }
  }
   var maxProfit = Math.max.apply(this, tmp);
   if(maxProfit <=0) {return 0;}
   return maxProfit;
};

maxProfit([7,1,5,3,6,4]);//test
```

When I invoke it in the chrome console or just run in the leetcode by click "Run Code" button, but it is wrong when I submit the code in the leetcode.

***The error message:***

[image]

I tried to ask in the leetcode forum, but there is no apply in past days.

Comment: The reason for the allocation failure is likely that your tmp array gets too long.
It tries to allocate a larger vector when running out of capacity but this fails, because no large enough heap chunk is available.
The garbage collection may be able to reclaim some space, but at some point it will be too much.
Note that the max size of prices is 10^5. Thus, your tmp array has 10^5 * 10^5 = 10^10 entries.
Even if one entry was just 1 byte (which it is not), this would already be roughly 10 Gigabytes.